# How to make SQL query elapse time between selected date and now?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let say i have a date field and i want to calculate the days between

Selected date on the date field and now() as in system date how do i make the query using SQL?

Comment: Could you at least show us your table structure?

Comment: checkout [DateDiff](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)

Comment: select DATEDIFF(date, NOW()) from table

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/03b79d/9/0

Answer (score 3):

```
select DATEDIFF(columnwithdatename, NOW()) from table
```

Comment: This is working thanks...i just want to complete all my understanding how about if i want to take date DATEDIFF between start and end date column?

Comment: select DATEDIFF(startdatecolumn, enddatecolumn) from table

Answer (score 1):

Use the DateDiff function:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

e.g.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MyDateColumn, NOW()) FROM MyTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

use the sql datediff function
for example

```
select datediff(day, myDate, getdate()) as daysAgo
from myTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using `DATEDIFF` SQL function (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff).

So for example:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(NOW(), your_date_field) FROM your_table;
```